# Select full row for the stats mode value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below -

```
id cola colb colc
1  45   ab    cd
1  45   ef    cd 
1  50   ab    av
2  20   cd    sc
2  13   cd    cd
2  20   as    sd
```

I want to first get the stats mode value of cola partition by id. In this case its 45 for 1 and 20 for 2 and then select the full row of the selected stats_mode value. is there any way to do it in one sql instead of creating inline queries?

Expected result:-

```
id cola colb colc
1  45   ab    cd
2  20   as    sd
```

Comment: there si not a predefined order in SQL so your "get first row"  have not sense .in SQL  .. you need  some values for define what is first and what is not .. ..

Comment: "**the** full row"? There are *two* rows for 1|45 and two rows for 2|20. Why are you only showing one of them each? What makes you decide for those particular rows?

Comment: What does stats mode mean ?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan: `STATS_MODE`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions154.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could try using some subquery

```
select m2.* from my_table m2 
inner join (
  select  min(m1.colb) min_colb, t1.cola, t1.id
  from  my_table m1
  inner join  (
    select cola, id 
    from  my_table 
    group by cola,id  
    having count(*)>1 
  ) t1 on t1.cola = m1.cola and t1.id = m1.id 
) t2 on t2.cola = m2.cola and t2.id = m2.id and t2.min_colb = m2.colb
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to do it in one sql instead of creating inline queries?

No, you need subqueries to perform this kind of data operations.

Answer (score 0):

The statistical mode is the most commonly occurring value.  You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by cnt desc) as seqnum_mode
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by id, cola) as cnt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum_mode = 1;
```